# Why does await is not working in my function?

Tags: javascript, async-await

I am trying to push in an array all the ids of objects that match my condition.

I am using a recursive function and I want to return a value when my recursive function has finished.

Here is my code :

```
const getFamilies = async function (family, famillesReliees) {
    await strapi.query('famille-de-materiel').findOne({ id: family })
        .then(res => {
            if (res.cats_enfant.length > 0) {
                res.cats_enfant.forEach(async enfant => {
                    famillesReliees = await getFamilies(enfant.id, famillesReliees)
                })
            } else {
                famillesReliees.push(res.id)
            }
        })
        return famillesReliees
}

async search() {
    let value = await getFamilies(2, [])
    return value
}
```

I don't understand why the "value" return before the end of the recursive function

Comment: `.then(console.log('getFamilies then'))` -> `.then(() => console.log('getFamilies then'))`

Comment: You're *immediately* calling `console.log` and assing its return value as the `then` function.

Comment: IN additon to the above, you're never awaiting the recursive call to `getFamilies`

Comment: The inner `getFamilies(enfant.id)` needs to be returned in a `Promise.all` for the outer `.then` to wait for it to finish

Comment: Also, what is `famillesReliees`? If it's a global array you're sooner or later going to run into the problems associated with trying to return a value from an async function

Comment: Thank you, what do you suggest then for `famillesReliees`

Answer (score 1):

This isn't doing what you think:

```
getFamilies(2).then(console.log('getFamilies then'))
```

This executes `console.log` *immediately* and passes its *result* (which is `undefined`) as the function to be executed after the `getFamilies` operation.

Wrap the `console.log` operation in a function to be executed later:

```
getFamilies(2).then(() => console.log('getFamilies then'))
```

Structurally, this is just like your use of `.then()` in the `getFamilies` function above.  The only differences are:

- There are no parameters/arguments for the function, so just use `()` instead of a variable name.  (Your callback function above has a parameter called `res`.)
- There's only one line in the function, so the curly braces `{}` aren't needed.  (Technically this also *returns* the result of that line, but in this case the returned result is `undefined` and nothing uses it so no harm done.)